# js code not working in IE and Edge

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

as a part of my Django app, I have a small js code that works fine in Chrome, but I just noticed that it is not working in IE or Microsoft Edge. What causes this? I have windows 10 and everything is the latest version, so why IE cannot run the js code? The part that I have a problem is this:

```
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown .nav-link')).forEach(function(el){
    el.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);
});
```

Comment: Please define "not working".... have you tried debugging your app with the dev tool (f12)?.... make sure you are selecting "Break on all exceptions" from the dropdown on the Debugging tab... (looks like a stop sign).... Provide a reproduction url with your questions if possible. On IE11, select Internet Options>Advanced tab, check "Always record developer console messages". Save changes.... IE11 will now list markup, security and Xss errors in the console

Comment: @RobParsons thanks for the pointers. I followed them and it seems this is the error: `Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'`

Comment: Hi, it appears that you are using a lower emulation mode for your site... (aka Compatibility view). F12>Emulation tab, will tell you which IE Emulation mode is being used and how it was established... eg. Enterprise Mode (IE8), Enterprise Mode Site lists.... It could be that you are developing on localhost which is mapping to the Intranet zone and putting your test site into Compatibility view in IE... File>Properties menu will tell you which IE security zone your site maps to...Internet Options>Security tab, INtranet sites>Advanced button... remove localhost from the list...

Comment: @RobParsons thanks for the input. I tried all of the investigations you mentioned. Emulation mode was `Edge` which was the highest version so it is not an old emulation. IE security is mapped to Intranet, but when I checked the list of intranet sites, the local host address was not there, so I cannot remove it from there